# Creating sub-array within array in reduce function

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have a multi-level object here and I'm simply trying to create a new array at the date level for `skus`. Basically, what I have now is:

```
name {
  date {
    reps
    sets
  }
  total
}
```

But I need a structure that creates a new array of skus at the date level like this:

```
name {
  date {
    reps
    sets
    skus {
      123 {
      
      }
      234 {

      }
    }
  }
  total
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
const res = [
      {name: "bob",sku: 123, reps: 2, sets: 2, date: '2020/03/03' },
      {name: "bob", sku: 234, reps: 15, sets: 2, date: '2020/03/03' },
      {name: "bob", sku: 345, reps: 26, sets: 5, date: '2020/03/05' },
      {name: "bob", sku: 456, reps: 11, sets: 8, date: '2020/03/06' }
    ]

    const dataMap = res.reduce((r, o) => {
      r[o.name] ??= {}
      r[o.name][o.date] ??= {sets: 0, reps: 0, total: 0, skus:[]}
      r[o.name][o.date].sets += +o.sets
      r[o.name][o.date].reps += +o.reps
      r[o.name][o.date].skus.push(o.sku)
      r[o.name][o.date][o.sku] ??= {}
      r[o.name].total ??= 0
      r[o.name].total += (+o.sets * +o.reps)
      return r
    }, {});
    
    document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(dataMap, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Any errors? Unexpected result?

Comment: @MattU it's telling me that skus.push is not a function right now. I just made a snippet for it, but I'm basically trying to make a skus array and then allow each sku within that array to also be an array so that I can store future attributes for each sku

Comment: @Geoff_S then you'll need to assign `[]` to `skus` first, and then you can start pushing into them

Comment: You currently have `skus:{}` which is an object, not an array. Change that to `skus:[]`.

Comment: @MattU I see, so I did make that change but now it just lists each sku in that array. How would I now make each of the listed skus its own array?

Comment: `r[o.name][o.date].skus.push({ [o.sku] : []})` is this what you wanted? This complicated data structure could get messy very fast!

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar that gives me "skus":{"123":[]},{"234":[]}     but I guess I was thinking I could get it like "skus":"123":[],"234":[]

Comment: the version that you want... is it in the correct JSON format?

Comment: yes it is, I think the issue is that I want objects here and not arrays